# Bulk read Couchbase documents

Tags: java, rx-java, couchbase

I want to asynchronously read a number of documents from a Couchbase bucket. This is my code:

```
JsonDocument student = bucketStudent.get(studentID);
```

The problem is for a large data file with a lot of studentIDs, it would take a long time to get all documents for these studentIDs because the `get()` method is called for each studentID. Is it possible to have a list of studentIDs as input and return an output of a list of students instead of getting a single document for each studentID?

Answer (score 1):

If you are running a query node, you can use N1QL for this. Your query would look like this:

```
SELECT * FROM myBucket USE KEYS ["key1", "key2", "key3"]
```

In practice you would probably pass in the array of strings as a parameter, like this:

```
SELECT * FROM myBucket USE KEYS ?
```

You will need a primary index for your bucket, or queries like this won't work.

Comment: NOTE this does not work on binary document,.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK couchbase SDK does not have a native function for a bulk `get` operation.

The node.js SDK has a `getMulti` method, but it's basically an iteration over an array and then `get()` is fired for each element.

I've found in my applications that the `key-value` approach is still faster than the `SELECT *` on a primary index but the N1QL query is remarkably close (on couchbase 5.x).

Just a quick tip: if you have A LOT of ids to fetch and you decide to go with the N1QL queries, try to split that list in smaller chunks. It's speeds up the queries and you can actually manage your errors better and avoid getting some nasty timeouts.

Comment: This is correct about there being no native function on the protocol level for bulk operations. That being said `getMutli` will be faster as it will dispatch all of the `get` operations at the same time.  Which will reduces the number of system calls and amount of work that is required by the application server.

Comment: this answer is obsolete.

Answer (score 1):

Retrieving multiple documents using the document IDs is not supported by default in the Couchbase Java SDK. To achieve that you'll need to use a `N1QL` query as below

```
SELECT S.* FROM Student S USE KEYS ["StudentID1", "StudentID2", "StudentID3"]
```

which would return an array of Documents with the given IDs. Construct the query with `com.couchbase.client.java.query.N1qlQuery`, and use either of below to execute

If you're using **Spring's CouchbaseTemplate**, you can use the below

```
List<T> findByN1QL(com.couchbase.client.java.query.N1qlQuery n1ql,
                          Class<T> entityClass)
```

If you're using **Couchbase's Java SDK**, you can use the below

```
N1qlQueryResult query(N1qlQuery query)
```

Note that you'll need an `index` on your bucket to run N1QL queries.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible now. The java sdk gives capability to do multi get. It is present in 2 flavours

1. Async bulk get
2. N1Q1 query. **Does not work with binary documents**

The Couchbase document suggests to use Async bulk get, But that has additional dependency on reactive java client. you can see official documentation [here](https://docs.couchbase.com/java-sdk/current/howtos/concurrent-async-apis.html#low-level-asynchronous-api-with-completablefutures).

There are several tutorial explaining the usage. [link](https://www.baeldung.com/async-batch-operations-in-couchbase) .

Here is how a sample get would look like, with java sdk 3.2

```
    List<String> docsToFetch = Arrays.asList("airline_112", "airline_1191", "airline_1203");

    Map<String, GetResult> successfulResults = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
    Map<String, Throwable> erroredResults = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();

    Flux.fromIterable(docsToFetch).flatMap(key -> reactiveCollection.get(key).onErrorResume(e -> {
        erroredResults.put(key, e);
        return Mono.empty();
    }).doOnNext(getResult -> successfulResults.put(key, getResult))).last().block();
```

[source](https://www.baeldung.com/async-batch-operations-in-couchbase) .